# Puppy does not seem to understand that she is not suposed to pee inside

Tags: dogs, toilet-training

I have a puppy - Presa Canario 3.5 months female. She does get walks every 3.5 hours. Sleeps in the crate during the night.

She does not seem to understand that she is not supposed to pee inside - I take her outside, she comes back inside, half an hour later she both pees and poops. Does not seem to be getting that she is not supposed to do it inside.

She is clean in the crate, but I can only crate her for so long.

Any advice?

Comment: Do you feed your dog on a schedule or does she able to eat whenever she wants? Do you feed her before or after walks?

Comment: In the morning before walks. She gets a potty break first thing in the morning, eats while I get dressed, then a 1 hour or so walk and I rush to work. No food in the house while I am at work.

Comment: Have you tried positive reinforcement training when she *does* go outside?  How do you normally respond when she does her business indoors?

Comment: I chastise her with no but no other punishment. I praise her when she goes outside. I will try with treats when she does go outside.